# Can a .NET console app terminate due to uncaught exception even if debugger is set to catch user uncaught exceptions?

Tags: .net

I'm using Windows 7 and visual studio 2010.
.NET console app... multi-threaded.

In a nutshell, the app terminates unexpectedly and leaves no indication of what went wrong.  I have it running as DEBUG in VS2010 debugger, with exceptions set to catch any user uncaught exception.  I also put break points at the return 0; in main()  (Just in case the app was exiting normally and not dying due to an exception.)

In the Output, after the app dies and the debugger detaches I see it exited with code 0x80000003 application failed to initialize.  That's strange considering it usually runs between 10-60 minutse before it terminates like this.

Also, it looks like I'm catching exceptions everywhere in my app and logging them to a file.  But the NLog file is empty (no exception caught and logged.)  The app is multi-threaded so there could be a place where I am forgetting to catch exception and it is bubbling up to the app domain.

I also defined an uncaught exception handler at the app domain level and have it logging to a file as well (code below).

```
    public static int Main(string[] argv)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=
         new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(
             OnUnhandledException);

        var simulator = new Simulator("client.config", _logger = new Logger());
        simulator.LoadScenario();
        simulator.PlayPause();
        simulator.Wait();  
        return 0;  // I set a breakpoint here and it never gets reached either.
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when you have an unhandled exception
    /// </summary>
    public static void OnUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    { 
        Exception exception = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;  // I set a breakpoint here.
        _logger.WriteError("Unhandled exception caught at App Domain.", exception); 
    }
```

Comment: SEH exception code 0x8000003 is a debugger break exception.  That's a bit Heisenburgian.  Turn on unmanaged debugging, this might be a breakpoint generated by the Windows heap manager when it detects heap corruption.

Comment: Interesting, this sounds like the likely cause.  I'm currently working on determining this.  You should almost post a real reply so I can accept this as the answer if turns out to be correct.

Comment: Ask a well documented question, I'll post a well documented non-Heisenburgian answer.

Comment: My question isn't documented well enough?  The whole point of my question is that I AM MISSING documentation.  And therefore, I provided everything I thought might be pertinent.  It turns out, the lone detail of the 0x80000003 error code was enough to trigger a correct assumption in your brain.  Well done Hans!  I have indeed verified your assumption was correct and I have corrupted the heap.  Thank you ever so much.  Now, I'll ask again, will you post a reply so I can mark your answer correct?  It's up to you my Heisenbergian friend.

Comment: Actually, to be more specific, I wasn't corrupting the heap.  There's a bug in Sql CE which corrupts the heap.  Good news is Microsoft patched it.  Make sure you are using SQL CE version 3.5.8080.50, otherwise you will hit this issue as well one day if you put the linq connector under heavy load.